# Problema em zerar o score de um jogo

Tags: exceção, lógica, c++11, vector

Bem, eu leio o livro do Bjarne sobre programação e estou aprendendo programação por lá, estou no capitulo 5 que é sobre erros, no final do capitulo tem uma lista de exercícios para que eu os faça, me deparei com um exercício em que tenho que criar uma especie de um joguinho que verifica um vetor de 4 numero de 1 a 9 que o usuário digita com o valor randômico criado no computador pra cada numero certo na posição certa que você acerta é um tatu e pra cada numero certo na posição errada é uma capivara, o problema é que de primeiro momento funciona, mas ai o que acontece é que o programa não zera o valor de tatus e capivaras, já tentei de tudo quanto é forma, será que alguém tem alguma sugestão? As vezes é alguma coisa boba que eu errei e nem percebi.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <locale>
using namespace std;

vector<int> chave; //chave q o user vai tentar advinhar
vector<int> adv; //vetor com os valores do user
int jogadas = 0; //quantitades de vezes que o jogador jogou
int tatu = 0; // numero certo no lugar certo
int capi = 0; // numero certo no lugar errado
const int jogador = 4;

class Deubad{
    //exceção do rolê que deu ruim
};

class acabou{
    //exceção do fim
};

int gerador(int s){
    srand(s); //gera uma seed nova pra cada vez que é chamado 
    for(int x = 0; x < 9; x++){ //gera um vetor de 1 a 9 ou seja com 10 valores dentro
        chave.push_back(x+1);  
    }
    random_shuffle(chave.begin(),chave.end()); //tipo embaralha as cartas hehe, lembrando que usa somente os 4 primeiros numeros da sequencia
    for(int x : chave){
        cout<<x<<endl; //isso é só pra listar, pois não sei usar depurador
    }
}

vector<int> inserir(vector<int> f){ //insere os valores que o user digitar
    for(int x = 0; x < 4;x++){
        int val;
        cin>>val;
        if(val == 0 || val > 9) throw Deubad{};
        else;
        f.push_back(val);
    }
    return f;
}

int verificar(){
    for(int x = 0; x < 4;x++){
        if(adv[x] == chave[x]){ //comparando se os números são de mesmo valor e mesma posição
            tatu += 1;
        }else{
        }
        for(int y = 0; y < 4;y++){
            if(adv[x] == chave[y] && adv[x] != chave[x]){ //comparando se os numeros são de mesmo valor e posição diferente
                capi += 1;
            }else{
            }
        }
    }
    jogadas += 1;
    cout<<"Você tem "<<tatu<<" tatus e "<<capi<<" capivaras..."<<endl;
    tatu = 0;
    capi = 0;
}

int ganhou(){ //verifica se o jogador acertou tudo
    int val = 1;
    if(tatu == 4){
        cout<<"Você ganhou!!!"<<endl;
        return val;
    }else{
        val = 2;
        return val;
    }
}

int jogardnov(){ // pergunta se o usuario quer jogar novamente
    char r = ' ';
    cout<<"Quer jogar novamente? Digite S para sim e N para não"<<endl;
    cin>>r;
    int val = 2;
    if(r == 'S' || r == 's'){
        return val;
    }else if(r == 'N' || r == 'n'){
        return 0;
    }else{
        throw Deubad{};
    }
}

void novament(){ //executa tudo dnovo
    do{
        cout<<"Você já tentou "<<jogadas<<" vezes"<<endl;
        tatu = 0;
        capi = 0;
        adv = inserir(adv);
        verificar();
        int vef = ganhou();
        if(vef == 1){
            if(jogardnov() == 2){
                break;
            }else{
                throw acabou{};
            }
        }else{
            tatu = 0;
            capi = 0;
            break;
        }
    } while(tatu != 4);
}

int main(){
try{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");
    cout<<"Isto é um jogo, mesmo que não tenha um grande gráfico é um jogo"<<endl
        <<"Esse jogo chama tatus e capivaras"<<endl //o charme do joguin tá no nome que ele recebe saca
        <<"Funciona da seguinte maneira, tenho uma chave de 4 digitos \n que contém números de 1 a 9 aqui comigo..."<<endl
        <<"Voce tem que ser ninja pra acertar tudo de primeira..."<<endl
        <<"Pra cada número certo no lugar certo que você tem tatu"<<endl
        <<"Já se você acertar o número no lugar errado você tem uma capivara"<<endl
        <<"Então vamos ver o que aconteceu..."<<endl
        <<"Preciso que você digite um número qualquer"<<endl;
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    if(chave.size() == 0){
        gerador(n);
    }else{
        srand(n);
        random_shuffle(chave.begin(),chave.end());
    }
    cout<<"Agora você vai preencher as suas possibilidades, \n com números de 1 a 9, não esqueça!!"<<endl;
    adv = inserir(adv);
    verificar();
    int val = ganhou();
    do{
        if(val == 1){
            val = jogardnov();
            if(val == 2){
                system("CLS");
                main();
            }else{
                return 0;
            }
        }else{
            novament();
        }
    }while(true);
}
catch(Deubad){
    cerr<<"Você digitou algo errado em... SEU BABACA ANALFABETO OTARIO"<<endl;
    novament(); 
}
catch(acabou){
    cerr<<"Seu arrogante não gostou do meu jogo seu babacão!! \nfalo mesmo não sou baú"<<endl;
}
}
```

Comment: todos os casos(perder, ganhar, etc...) não esta zerando?

Comment: Fui rever o código por inteiro achei o erro

Comment: Coloca a resposta então.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu encontrei o erro, não é problema com score e sim com vetor.

O vetor q você digitou na rodada passada continua ali, e por isso atrapalha verificar os itens do vetor. Usei uma linha pra resolver esse problema:

```
adv.clear();
```